# C++ File Output Garbage

Tags: c++, fileoutputstream, garbage

this is giving me a wicked headache and was hoping I could find some help. The program is supposed to read in a program of 19 integers, then output the smallest (2nd integer) and largest (5th integer) to the screen. However, all my results yield garbage.

```
#include iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//the goal of this program is to read in numbers from a file, then output the 
//highest number and the lowest number to the screen
int main() {

ifstream fileInput;
int nOne, nTwo, nThree, nFour, nFive, nSix, nSeven, nEight, nNine, nTen,     //there are 19 numbers in the file
    nEleven, nTwelve, nThirteen, nFourteen, nFifteen, nSixteen, nSeventeen,
    nEighteen, nNineteen;


cout << "Opening File" << endl;

fileInput.open("Lab12A.txt");            //the file is opened
if (fileInput.fail())
{
    cout << "Input file opening failed. \n"; //the fail check doesnt pop up, so the file has been opened.
    exit(1);
}

fileInput >> nOne >> nTwo >> nThree >> nFour >> nFive >> nSix >> nSeven >> nEight
    >> nNine >> nTen >> nEleven >> nTwelve >> nThirteen >> nFourteen >> nFifteen   //this is where they should be extracted
    >> nSixteen >> nSeventeen >> nEighteen >> nNineteen;




cout << "The highest number is " << nTwo << endl;
cout << "The lowest number is " << nFive << endl;

fileInput.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you write code to solve the problem... Have you learned about arrays yet?

Comment: Typo on the first line.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: What is the format of the input file and the exact output? I cannot reproduce this with space separated input numbers.

Comment: By the way, why is it I'm seeing that awful `system("pause");` line so often on this site?  Where are so many people getting that from?

Comment: @FeiXiang , the typo doesn't exist in the code, that was just a copy/paste error. I do know arrays, however the way I have it written is directly from the book, using the extraction operator to copy the data to the variables. I wanted to save using an array until I couldn't salvage this. The input file is a .txt file and the exact output is "The highest number is -858993460 
The lowest number is -858993460"

Comment: @DanielSchepler Lol my professor insisted on that.

Comment: It's not your program's job to keep the console window open. You should configure your IDE to do that, or use something like a batch file to execute your program. Like I said before, I can't reproduce this problem. Please post the contents of the input file. You should also ask your professor how to read input into an array with a loop.

Comment: @FeiXiang Here's the contents

13 4329 534
340 -256 1024 593 -53 -26 493 
649 2018 -29 -58 343 902 81
964 -192

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all... Note that -858993460 is 0xFFFFFFFFCCCCCCCC in hexadecimal, which is likely some sort of magic debugging value. Try asking your professor to check to make sure you have everything set up right.

Comment: Just as a wild guess, is it possible that the text file editor you used to create `Lab12A.txt` inserted a Unicode BOM mark into the file?  Then, maybe that caused the standard library to put the input stream into error mode on trying to read the first number.

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: Directly from the book? Burn the book.

Comment: What you mean with "largest fifth"? and "smallest second"?

Answer (score 1):

I wished to add only a comment but since I can't do that, I leave it as an answer.

I have copied your file and created a text file to try to reproduce your issue. At first everything went well (No issue at all). But with comment from **Daniel Schepler**, I changed file encoding to **UTF8-BOM** (You can do that easily from Notepad++ Encoding menu) and tried again. I got same values you posted. I can't give more explanation to exactly how values are to be interpreted but I wish someone with more experience enlighten us here.

Comment: It's just causing undefined behavior (uninitialized variables) because it's not able to successfully read any values.  So the exact values you're getting in this case are meaningless, and would also be likely to vary based on optimization settings or platform.

Answer (score 1):

First I wanted to thank everyone who looked at and commented on this I greatly appreciate it, the issue was ultimately pinned down to needing a full path to the .txt file as opposed to the relative path I initially posted. For what ever reason, my compiler couldn't recognize the file without it. Seems like a silly mistake but I'm relatively new to this so those are sure to squeak by. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `std::vector` pushing the values then sorting the container and finally print the second and fifth elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main(){

    std::ifstream in("test.txt");

    std::vector<int> vecInt;
    int value;

    while(in >> value)
        vecInt.push_back(value);
    in.close();

    std::sort(vecInt.begin(), vecInt.end());

    // second value is at index 1 and fifth value is at index 4
    for(auto i(0); i != vecInt.size(); ++i)
        if(i == 1 || i == 4)
            std::cout << vecInt[i] << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- I am not sure about what you mean with "largest fifth integer".